# PHP - Search for different variations of email addresses in a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to figure out how to use a PHP preg_replace to replace an email address in a string with (email hidden). I'm building a app where I don't want customers to post their contact information. Most people are starting to get smart by using the following:

james (at) yahoo dot com

james at example dot com

How can I stop this from happening?

How can I add it to this:

```
$emailHidden = 'james at example dot com';

$emailHidden = 'james (at) example dot com';

$emailHidden = 'james at example.com';

$emailHidden = preg_replace('/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i','(email hidden)',$emailHidden); // extract email
```

Also, I still want to remove regular email addresses. e.g. james@yahoo.com

Comment: Cayce, yes... I want my customers to pay to see any contact information.

Comment: $hideEmail = 'Hi, you can reach me at james at example dot com.

Comment: The above code in my question works for regular email addresses. I'm trying to stay one step ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
$emailHidden = 'james at example dot com';
$emailHidden = 'james (at) example dot com';
$emailHidden = 'james at example.com';

$emailHidden = preg_replace('/[[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[ ]?[\(]?(@|at)[\)]?[ ]?[A-Z0-9.-]+[ ]?[\(]?(\.|dot)[)]?[ ]?[A-Z]{2,4}/i','(email hidden)',$emailHidden); // extract email
```

Will capture:

james at google dot com
 james@google.com
 james@google(dot)com
 james at google.com
 james (at) google (dot) com

Comment: This matches `--- atatatatatatatatat)...dotdotdot...AaAAAAAaaaaaaAAAAAA`

Comment: I've removed the +'s from the (@|at) (\.|dot). But it will still match this pattern. It could be made stricter, but I think the questioner is aiming to catch as much as possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, if you want to replace a regular email to some other format.

```
$email = 'somebody@anywhere.com';
$newEmail = preg_replace('/([A-Z0-9._%+-]+)@([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})/i', ' $1 (at) $2', $email);
echo $newEmail;
```

Output is:

```
somebody (at) anywhere.com
```

Or if you want to catch the others, then you can use these regexes:

```
$email = 'james at example dot com';
$emailHidden = preg_replace('/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[^\s] at [A-Z0-9.-]+[^\s] dot [A-Z]{2,4}/i', 'hidden email', $email);

$email = 'james (at) example dot com';
$emailHidden = preg_replace('/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[^\s] \(at\) [A-Z0-9.-]+[^\s] dot [A-Z]{2,4}/i', 'hidden email', $email);

$email = 'james at example.com';
$emailHidden = preg_replace('/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[^\s] at [A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i', 'hidden email', $email);
```